# Getting a detailed callstack log

Tags: visual-studio, debugging

Is this possible in Visual Studio to generate a text list of the methods that are being called, and possibly execution time [of returned methods]? I know about a lot of approaches to profile an application, but I think that having a clear - even if long - callstack would be helpful in improving launch performances.

Answer (score 1):

[Here's a code project article about this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11132/Walking-the-callstack)
It basically boils down to using the `GetThreadContext()` to capture the context of the current thread  and then using `StackWalk64()` to walk the stack. Alternatively you can also use `CaptureStackBackTrace()`.
These functions will only get you the list of addresses that make the stack. To get the names of the functions and line numbers you'll need to use functions from `dbghelp.dll` like 
`SymGetModuleInfo64()`

Comment: Will the symbols shown be using types from .Net, or some linked names (Don't know how it's called)? I've made something very similar to this, and being coding on Monodroid, all I got was very obscure Java methods.

Comment: Ideally, I'd like a StackTrace that only contains non-compiled code. Anyway, I'll check that link!

Comment: All of this refers to getting a stack trace for C or C++, not .net. for .net there'll be something else which I don't know about.